# Reference request on Riemann-Hilbert correspondence

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I'm looking for any books, lecture notes, e.t.c for the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence in the form of the following equivalence between flat $G$-connections, $G$-local systems and Homomorphisms from a fundamental group to $G$.